# HT12e: How is this a 2¹² encoder?

Tags: rf, encoder

I am using HT12E, for a rf transmitter circuit. As per the datasheet HT12E is a 2¹² encoder.

Ideally such an encoder must have 2¹² inputs and 12 outputs. In addition to that all the inputs should be 1 exclusively.

When i look at the IC, I see 12 inputs A0-A7 + AD8-AD11, which go into the transmission gate circuit of the IC.

Can someone help me understand this part of the working ?

Comment: I haven't looked, but from your description it appears that "\$2^{12}\$ inputs" (your term) means instead "\$2^{12}\$ symbols." The 12 inputs make sense then.

Comment: that appears to be a type of parallel to serial converter ... it encodes 12 inputs into a bit stream ... 12 inputs and 1 output

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're conflating a couple of definitions of the word "encoder". In this case, the chip is taking 12 binary inputs and encoding them as a serial word along with some synchronization information. The resulting word has 2<sup>12</sup> different states or values.

There is a different kind of (combinatorial) circuit that accepts 2<sup>N</sup> separate inputs and encodes the highest-valued one as an N-bit binary number. This is known as a "priority encoder".

Answer (score 2):

A chip with 2<sup>12</sup> inputs would have \$ ( {2 ^ {12}} ) ^{12} \$ possible combinations.

A 12-bit chip has 4096 combinations.